# How to read, write and query data in Firebase Realtime Database using Firebase SDK v9 (Modular)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do you perform read and write operations and query data from Firebase Realtime Database, where the traditional syntax in v8 goes like this:

```
const snapshot = await firebase.database().ref("/path").once("value")
```

Considering the sample data:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "user1" : {
      "age" : 34,
      "name" : "user1"
    },
    "user2" : {
      "age" : 23,
      "name" : "user2"
    },
    "user345" : {
      "age" : 19,
      "name" : "user345"
    },
    "user4" : {
      "age" : 15,
      "name" : "user4"
    },
    "user56" : {
      "age" : 45,
      "name" : "user56"
    },
    "user9435" : {
      "age" : 8,
      "name" : "user9435"
    }
  }
}
```

Also how would you use the methods `equalTo(), orderByChild(), etc`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<del>**Disclaimer:** The v9 modular SDK is a beta release. The syntax may (or may not) change but I'll try to update the answer if any asap.</del> Benefits of this upgrade can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#benefits).

The modular SDK cannot be used over CDN and you need to use npm or yarn for the time being. I've tested this in a Vue web-app.

**1. Initialize the Firebase App:**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = { 
  apiKey: "<api-key>",
  authDomain: "<project-id>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<project-id>.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "<project-id>",
  storageBucket: "<project-id>.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "0000000000",
  appId: "<app-id>",
}

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

**2. Create a Database Instance and Reference:**

```
import { getDatabase, ref } from "firebase/database"

const db = getDatabase(app) // <-- Pass in the initialized app

//Creating the reference (The path in db you are trying to read/write/update)
const dbRef = ref("/users")
```

**3. Read Operation and Listeners:**

You need to use `get()` method to retrieve data which accepts a query as parameter. If you are simply reading the data without any sorting or filtering, just pass the reference created above in the `query()`. (Note: Passing the reference directly in get() works in this case)

```
import { get, query, onValue } from "firebase/database"

const usersSnapshot = await get(query(dbRef)) //This should get the whole users node from db.

//To add a listener you can use the onValue() method like,
onValue(query(dbRef), snapshot => {
  console.log(snapshot.val())
})

//
```

In v8, the syntax for events looks like `.on("event_name")`. In v9, all events are a method which can be used this way:

```
import { onChildAdded, onChildChanged, onChildRemoved } from "firebase/database"

onChildAdded(query(dbRef), (snapshot) => {
  console.log("child added");
  console.log(snapshot.val()); // Logs newly added child
});

onChildChanged(query(dbRef), (snapshot) => {
  console.log("child changed")
  console.log(snapshot.val()); // Logs updated value of changed child
});
 
onChildRemoved(query(dbRef), (snapshot) => {
  console.log("child removed");
  console.log(snapshot.val()); // Logs value of removed child
});
```

**4. Writing Data:**

```
// You maybe have figured out the upgrade trend ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

import { set, update } from "firebase/database"

const newUserName = "user1122"
const userRef = ref(`users/${newUserName}`)
 
await set(userRef, {name: newUserName, age: 11})
await update(userRef, {age: 12})
```

**5. Working with lists:**

This is best part and it now kind of feels similar to adding stages in a MongoDB Aggregation.

```
import { query, orderByChild, orderByValue, orderByKey, limitToLast } from "firebase/database"

//Example: getting 3 youngest users from the db
const usersSnapshot = await get(query(dbRef, ...[orderByChild("age"), limitToFirst(3)]))
```

The first parameter in the `query()` is the Database Reference and all following parameters are QueryConstraints and can be either of these methods: `'endAt' | 'endBefore' | 'startAt' | 'startAfter' | 'limitToFirst' | 'limitToLast' | 'orderByChild' | 'orderByKey' | 'orderByPriority' | 'orderByValue' | 'equalTo';`. You can pass them as individual parameters instead of using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) as I've used.

I've found no issues using the modular SDK so far. Just make sure you've imported all things which are needed.

PS: Just in-case if you use Vue, React or any framework with hot-reload when developing, you might encounter the "Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app)" error. Checking if `firebase.apps.length` is 0 helps and that's done this way in modular SDK:

```
import { getApps, initializeApp } from "firebase/app"

if (!getApps().length) initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```