# Firebase realtime db limitToFirst(10) doesnt working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am facing issue i am trying to get only 10 data from firebase but how can i achieve that if ref(database, "messages/").limitToFirst(10) is throwing:

> ref(...).limitToFirst is not a function

My code:

```
const newMsg = ref(database, 'messages/').limitToFirst(10);
onChildAdded(newMsg, (data) => {
    if(data.val().name != name){
        var divData = '<div class="message"><div class="others">'+data.val().name+': </div><div>'+data.val().message+'</div></div>'; 
        //oponent message
        $("#chat-history").append(divData);
    }else{
        var divData = '<div class="message"><div class="user">'+data.val().name+': </div><div>'+data.val().message+'</div></div>'; 
        //sent message
        $("#chat-history").append(divData);
    }
});
```

Where database is

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getDatabase(app);
```

And my imports look like this:

```
import {initializeApp} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-app.js";
import {
    getDatabase,
    set,
    ref,
    push,
    child,
    onValue,
    onChildAdded
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-database.js";
```

**EDIT:**
After a hour i see where is the problem in my import i need to add query,  limitToLast

```
import {
    getDatabase,
    set,
    ref,
    query,
    push,
    child,
    onValue,
    onChildAdded,
    limitToLast
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-database.js";
```

And in my function just call it like this:

```
const newMsg = query(ref(database, 'messages/'), limitToLast(10));
onChildAdded(newMsg, (data) => {
```

Comment: Have you set the proper rules?

Comment: Yes i am sure, maybe my syntax is bad? Could anyone look at it please ? :)

Comment: Add then to you question.

Answer (score 2):

In the new Modular SDK (`v9.0.0+`), you can build a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.query) using [`query()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database#query) function (instead of chaining the [`QueryConstraint`s](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.queryconstraint)):

```
import { ref, query, limitToFirst } from "firebase/database"

const newMsg = query(ref(database, 'messages/'), limitToFirst(10))

onChildAdded(newMsg, (data) => {
  // ...
})
```

The new SDK uses a functional syntax unlike the older name-spaced one so `limitToFirst` is a top-level function now as in above code snippet.

Also checkout:

- [How to read, write and query data in Firebase Realtime Database using Firebase SDK v9 (Modular)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67571500/13130697)
- [Working with lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data)